# Import Microstation geometry to ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, data-interoperability, microstation

I have geometry alignments of land parcels defined in MicroStation InRoads V8i. Instead of using the dgn files I want to use the geometry files. I have ArcGIS 10 Desktop advanced license with Data Interoperability extension. InRoads will export to a LandXML file but ArcGIS is not able to read the files - "AdvanceToElement: unable to find xml element.

Does anyone know what process needs to happen in order to utilize these files?

Right now I am creating a separate dgn using the alignments and then bringing those into ArcMap but this is not feasible for the long-term and I want to automate the process of reading the geometry. I will not actually bring the geometry into ArcMap but overwrite current shapes with the Inroad geometry (geometry transfer).

An alternative would be to create shapefiles from the alignment files.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged `data-interoperability`. So, if you have data interop installed, you should be able to import the LandXML files. It is listed amongst the **[supported formats](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/supported-formats)**.

If not, I know you can translate LandXML to any ESRI compatible format using **[FME](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/landxml/landxml.htm)**. It is likely that you will need to do some processing to extract the features in FME or Data Interoperability.